# Exit the script if any statement fails

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using nested `if` statements in my shell script. If any statement fails, it has to come out of the script with out executing other sections in the script. I tried using `exit 1` and `set -e`.

I'm not able to use `set -e` as I have used a few `grep` statements which would return non zero status.

Could someone please help me How to stop executing a script if any statements fails?

Comment: Doesn’t `exit 1` work?

Comment: I'd recommend fixing the `grep`'s that aren't returning correctly as well. Enabling `set -e` is a level of conformance that you're demanding of your script, so you're basically working against it rather than using its enforcements. Just my $0.02.

Comment: By "any statements" you seem to mean "almost any statements".

Answer (score 4):

You can still use `set -e`.  If you have specific statement which you *expect* to fail, you simply need to catch the error state and "handle" it:

```
$ cat 454756.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
[[ 1 -eq 2 ]] || :
echo "Still got here!"
$ ./454756.sh
Still got here!
```

`set -e` will abort the script on any *uncaught* error condition.  Otherwise you would not be able to use `if` statements.

```
# this also still works
set -e
if /bin/false; then
    echo "nope"
else
    echo "yep"
fi
```

The incantation `|| :` is a succinct way to "eat" any error thrown by any command, which is handy when you're wanting to use `set -e` and have specific commands whose failure is *perfectly okay*.

Another way to do this is to unset `-e` before the command in question, and reset it afterward:

```
set -e
do_stuff
set +e
/bin/false
set -e
```

Comment: Might worth mentioning `true` and `:` are effectively the same and `true` is a bit more explicit

Comment: In bash source they're implemented via same function, and both return exit status of success no matter what, and take arguments without doing anything

Comment: Fair enough, I sit corrected.